# Iterate through api data on button click angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contentful

I have some data that I have called from an external api. Now what I want to do is have a button on my page that iterates through the data..

so.. for example say I have a page on my site that has a title and some text which comes from the api and the data im recieving back from the api is

```
{
    fields: {
        title: 'title 1',
        text: 'this is some text'
    }
},
{
    fields: {
        title: 'title 2',
        text: 'this is some more text'
    }
},
```

now I want the first item to be inserted into the title div and then the text inserted into the text div

so something like..

```
<div class="title">{{response.fields.title}}</div>
<div class="text">{{response.fields.text}}</div>
```

then when I click a `next` button on my page I want the title and text to update to the second item so `title 2` and `text` I'm not 100% how I would do something like this..

So my set up is as follows

**contentful.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ContentfulService {
  private cdaClient = createClient({
    space: CONFIG.space,
    accessToken: CONFIG.accessToken
  });

  constructor() { }

  getProgramItems(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
      content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.programItems
    }, query))
    .then(res => res.items);
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContentfulService } from '../contentful.service';
import { Entry } from 'contentful';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  // define private class properties
  private programItems: Entry<any>[] = [];
  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.contentfulService.getProgramItems()
      .then(programItems => this.programItems = programItems)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(this.programItems);
      });
  }
```

so basically I want to have the title and text of each program item to update the title and text div on the page on a button click, I thought about using a ES6 generator but Im not sure how I would use it in this case.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: did the answer help at all? Would appreciate it if you can accept/mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="title">{{currentItem.title}}</div>
<div class="text">{{currentItem.text}}</div>
<button (click)="goToNext()">Next</button>

public counter: number = 0;
public currentItem: Entry<any>;

goToNext() {
    if (this.counter > this.programItems.length) this.counter = this.programItems.length;
    this.currentItem = this.programItems[this.counter];
    this.counter++;
}
```

You could try something like above.

Assuming you have got your `programItems` array back from the service and all populated correctly, then you could use a counter as the array index and increment it every time you click the Next button.